# Google spreadsheet count words

Tags: google-sheets

I have spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19GrXAFLpv6jz9OzDum-fyfP_m-RZFCNrQ0rr1vd5bYI/edit?usp=sharing

I want to count percent of wins(W) in C column and write it to C1 cell. I plan to add many rows.

I know VBA little bit, but not found how to use it inside Spreadsheet.

How to use VBA there?

And how to do this with fuction button?

Comment: It's not clear for me what you are asking. Regarding VBA in Google spreadsheets, check out [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)

Comment: I'm asking default way to count words "W" in column to receive answer 15 from 25 or 60%. As alternative I know VBA, and if somebody know how to use it there - it would help. As I can see in your link it`s JavaScript, thank you, at least something I can try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of something similar to VBA as the percentage could be calculate by using built-in functions.

The column C has values L or W. To calculate the percentage of W use the following formula in C1:

```
=COUNTIF(C3:C,"W")/COUNTA(C3:C)
```

- `COUNTIF(C3:C,"W")` counts cells from C3 to the last cell in column C with `W`.
- `COUNTA(C3:C)` counts all the cells from C3 to the last cell in column C with any alphabetic value.

To display the result as percentage apply the % format.